# What is the proper replacement of the Resteasy 3.X PreProcessInterceptor?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm building rest service using an authentication/authorization mechanism as described in this tutorial: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/26/jax-rs-resteasy-basic-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial/

Basically it uses the [PreProcessInterceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/interception/PreProcessInterceptor.html) interface to scan the target method for annotations (from [javax.annotation.security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/package-summary.html) package) which describe the required roles to access that method. As the the authenticator here is an interceptor, it can cancel the target method invocation, returning a 401 (unauthorized) if needed.

The problem here is that the interface org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.PreProcessInterceptor is deprecated in the current RestEasy version (3.0.1), and I'm having problems trying to implement the same behaviour with the standard JAX-RS interfaces.

I'm using the javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptor interface to intercept the call. But somehow the server never calls it: the interceptor is just ignored.

I'm registering the interceptors/resources the same way as I did with the former PreProcessInterceptor, and using the same @Provider and @ServerInterceptor annotations:

ServerApplication:

```
public class ServerApplication extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

     private final HashSet<Object> singletons = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();

     public ServerApplication() {
         singletons.add(new SecurityInterceptor());
         singletons.add( ... ); //add each of my rest resources
     }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

SecurityInterceptor:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class SecurityInterceptor implements javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptor {
     @Override
     public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context){
            //code that is never called... so lonely here...
     }
}
```

Any insights about how can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

RESTEasy 3.x.x conforms to the JAX-RS 2.0 specification.

What you are trying to do could be accomplished (maybe better) with:

```
@Provider
public class SecurityInterceptor 
      implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter {
     @Override
     public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext){
       if (not_authenticated){ requestContext.abortWith(response)};
     }
}
```

since the `ReaderInterceptor` is invoked only if the underlying `MessageBodyReader.readFrom` is called by the standard JAX-RS pipeline, not fromthe application code.

The reason why your interceptor is not called, though, could be the  `@ServerInterceptor` annotation, which is a RESTEasy extension.

The spec states at §6.5.2 that a interceptor is globally registered, unless the `@Provider` is annotated with a `@NameBinding` annotation, but I don't know if `RESTEasy` can handle a `@ServerInterceptor` if it's not explicitly  registered as shown in [RestEASY Interceptor Not Being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344311/resteasy-interceptor-not-being-called)

Comment: Using the ContainerRequestFilter, how can I get the annotations of the target method? The filter / interceptor needs to know that to properly allow or deny the invocation, based on the user roles.

Comment: `ContainerRequestFilter.getUriInfo().getMatchedResources()` returns the list of the matched resource objects. There you can parse the annotations matching the actual called methods

Comment: I think you meant `requestContext.getUriInfo().getMatchedResources()`. Anyway, this method is not quite as easy to use like in the former `PreProcessInterceptor`, since I don't have direct access to the target `java.lang.reflect.Method`. But I'll mark the answer as accepted, since it solves the problem.

Comment: It's what I meant. Sorry for the typo.. Have you investigated instead using `requestContext.setSecurityContext()` to inject your authentication and then delegate to a `@RolesAllowed` annotation?

Comment: Injecting `ResourceInfo` using `@Context` annotation will give you access to the target `Method`. See related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29201811/3323963

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get access to the underlying `java.lang.reflect.Method` (like you used to be able to get by implementing `AcceptedByMethod`), you can do the following:

```
ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) 
            requestContext.getProperty("org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker");
Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();
```

Comment: How about getting a httpRequest from the requestContext. I have a requirement to read the InputStream from the httpRequest. how to do that ?Or is a way there i can get InputStream from the containerrequestcontext?

Comment: I getting null reference from methodInvoker, don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted to get access to the underlying `java.lang.reflect.Method` and tried mtpettyp's answer with Resteasy 3.0.8, but that was returning null on the getProperty call. I am also using Spring and resteasy-spring although I don't believe that should impact this at all.

If you run into my situation and are implementing a Post Matching `ContainerRequestFilter` (you kind of have to if you were expecting to get the matched resource method anyway) then you can actually cast the `ContainerRequestContext` to the implementation Resteasy has for the Post Match scenario. The [PostMatchContainerRequestContext](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/core/interception/PostMatchContainerRequestContext.html) has a reference to the ResourceMethodInvoker.

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
    PostMatchContainerRequestContext pmContext = (PostMatchContainerRequestContext) context;

    Method method = pmContext.getResourceMethod().getMethod();

    /* rest of code here */
}
```