# jersey skip filtering on specific resource

Tags: jersey, jetty

I have REST API application running in Jetty + Jersey, all the requests will be filtered by some security filter,which is provided some excluded paths defined in config file. With old version Jersey 2.5 the API works fine, now i upgraded Jersey to 2.22.1, the excluded paths are subjected to filtering too and failed because no authentication token were provided.

here is my filter:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, DynamicFeature { 
...
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

   if (getExcludeUrlPatterns() != null) {
            for (String urlPattern : getExcludeUrlPatterns()) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath()); <-- here went wrong
                if (m.matches()) {
                    // skip filtering
                }
            }
        }

        // continue filtering.
}
}
```

here is my resource:

```
@Path("/version")
public class VersionResource {
   ... 
   @GET
    @ResponseClass(AppVersion.class)
    public Response getVersion() {
        AppVersion version =
                new AppVersion()
                        .withBuildPlan(BUILD_PLAN_SETTING)
                        .withBuildNumber(BUILD_NUMBER_SETTING)
                        .withBuildTimestamp(BUILD_TIMESTAMP_SETTING)
        return Response.ok(version).build();
    }
}
```

Excluded url paths:

```
/status,/status/?.*,/version,..
```

as I debugged the code, i noticed for an excluded request context "/myresources/version", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath() return 'version', however the Pattern is like '/version', thus it doesn't match the pattern and continue the authentication process, and further failed. anyone understand why it works like this?

I use Jersey 2.22.1 and jetty-maven-plugin 9.2.1.v20140609, here is my pom.xml

```
   <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <jetty.version>9.2.1.v20140609</jetty.version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-jetty-connector</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
   <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You can get the absolute URI with uriInfo.getAbsolutePath(), and just do some parsing. Or you can use one of the strategies mentioned in [10.5 and 10.6](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9988) for assigning methods to filter, or ring up your own [using ResourceInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32229156/2587435)

Comment: Or you might just be able to use uriInfo.getAbsoluteUri().getPath()