# Java Decorate Functions

Tags: java, function, decorator

I am new to Java so apologies if this is a simple thing. I have built decorators in Python for authorizing RESTFul endpoints in Flask and have just built my first Java Webserver but am unable to figure out how to create a similar decorator in Java.

I want to do some pre-checks before running the method (i.e. is the user allowed to access this route). Ideally this would be a decorator like `@authorize` that, if authorized, will execute the method, but if unauthorized then it would through a 403 error instead.

```java
@Path("/")
public final class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @authorize                           // How would I implement this?
    public String sayHelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am using Grizzly as the web Framework and I will be using an external Policy Management System (Apache Ranger) for managing authorization.

Comment: Annotations in java probably are not made for this purpose. It cannot be ruled out fully, but the code/effort you would need to make it work would be substantial.  A better design pattern, with proper chain of responsibility will be quick and efficient.

Comment: @Kris That is wrong. The whole idea of the JAX-RS framework is to enable **declarative** programming via **annotations**!

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: defining such custom annotations is *exactly* how you can approach such things in Java. The JAX-RS specification provides all the things you need for such kind of [method binding](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter12/per_jax_rs_method_bindings.html).

The thing that is slightly more complicated: how to nicely do that for the framework that you are using.

With JAX-RS and Jersey for example, creating your own annotations is well documented. And Jersey might be a good starting point, as that is simply a straight forward way to get JAX-RS working.

So, first you start by learning how to use Jersey in general, for example from [vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html). Next: you can start to add your custom annotations, see [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/custom-entity-validation.html) for an example.

There is even an existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228136/can-i-add-a-custom-annotation-to-jax-rs-method-to-validate-access) about using custom annotations for access validation.

Comment: "It depends", "RT...M" and some links do not make a good answer, IMO. You could request clarification (i.e. ask about the framework) via a comment...

Comment: My comment did not have a "technical basis" whatsoever - I basically know nothing about Java+Web, REST, JAX, Jersey etc. I only noticed that the answer 1. implicitly asks for clarification (which should be done via a comment), 2. is borderline to 'link only', and 3. suggests that the question may be a dupe. These are three red flags for me that make me wonder whether this answer should exist in its current form (Maybe someone can convince me that I'm wrong here, I just wanted to mention it...)

Comment: @Marco13 I reworked things to be more precise. The point is: the jaxrs spec enables annotations. How you do it to get to a working end to end solution depends on your framework. Jersey is the most simple one, thus I linked to it. Closing as DUP to that last link ... wouldnt work, as we dont know where exactly the OP is coming from.

Comment: I hesitatingly remove the downvote, but still wonder whether this answer is really helpful for the asker or future readers. (The one that you linked to contains code and more details, but I cannot say how large the overlap (on a technical level) is to this one...)

Comment: @Marco13 I appreciate your focus on quality. I agree, this is probably not the greatest question of today, and so is the answer. But I am also sure you could find 10, 20 questions/answers here today that are much worse.

Comment: @GhostCat, thank you heaps for the answer I will look into the links you have provided and get back to you. I have also updated the question with the Frameworks I am using

Comment: @Marco13, sorry the question is vague and poorly structured, I am unfamiliar with Java and unsure how I should change it to make it better. I am looking for how to implement a python functionality (Decorators) in Java with a RESTFul service as the example